# What is the best way to switch views/usercontrols in MVVM-light and WPF?

Tags: wpf, mvvm-light

I'm relatively new to WPF and MVVM and the hardest thing I have found is how to simply switch a usercontrol or a view in an application.

In winforms, to have a control remove itself you would simple say                                        this.Parent.Controls.Remove(this);

In WPF there is no generic Parent control, you would have to typecast it to the specific type (i.e. Grid) and then remove it.

This also seems to break the MVVM architecture. I have also tried data templates and content presenters, which work well, except for the fact that I can't change the datacontext from code, since the datacontext is always the viewmodellocator.

Are pages the acceptable way to do this in WPF now?  What if I had a grid with a custom usecontrol and I wanted to switch it based on some variable in the viewModel?  It seems like the simplest tasks cannot be accomplished easily in WPF.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You would do so in your parent ViewModel.

For example, if your page (call it `PageViewModel`) had two views (`ViewModelA` and `ViewModelB`), you would have a property on `PageViewModel` called `CurrentView`, and this would determine which View is visible. When `PageViewModel.CurrentView` is set to an instance of `ViewModelA`, then ViewA's DataTemplate is used to draw the content. When it's set to an instance of `ViewModelB`, ViewB's DataTemplate is displayed.

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:PageViewModel}">
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentView}" />
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ViewModelA}">
    <TextBlock Text="I'm ViewModelA" />
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ViewModelB}">
    <TextBlock Text="I'm ViewModelB" />
</DataTemplate>
```

It would be ideal to call the switch views command from the parent view (in this case the DataTemplate for the `PageViewModel`), however if you wanted to switch views from within ViewModelA/B, you can either hook up the event manually when the objects get created (`CurrentView.ChangeViewCommand = this.ChangeViewCommand`) or look into a messaging system. MVVM Light has a simple `Messenger` class which I found was fairly easy to use, or Prism has a more advanced `EventAggregator`

If you want to switch Views for the same ViewModel, I would recommend a Mode property that gets used to determine which view to use. For example:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ViewA" DataType="{x:Type local:MyViewModel}">
    <TextBlock Text="I'm ViewModelA" />
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Key="ViewB" DataType="{x:Type local:MyViewModel}">
    <TextBlock Text="I'm ViewModelB" />
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MyViewModel}">
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding }">
        <ContentControl.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource ViewA}" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Mode}" Value="2">
                        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource ViewB}" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ContentControl.Style>
    </ContentControl>
</DataTemplate>
```

**EDIT**

I actually see this kind of question come up a lot, so posted something about it [here](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/05/28/switching-between-viewsusercontrols-using-mvvm/) if anyone is interested

Comment: This is pretty much what I was looking for.  If I understand correctly, you can use DataTriggers to bind to a value and then switch the content on the fly.  Does this work for other controls such as ContentPresenter?

Comment: @JReed Sure, I don't see why not. In the 2nd example I'm switching the `ContentTemplate` property of a `ContentControl`, but you can switch out almost any property on any control based on a Trigger

Comment: What if either viewModel needs some data before initialisation so they don't have a parameter-less constructor?

Comment: @EmpereurAiman Then whatever code is responsible for creating the VM should pass it the correct parameters :)

Comment: My bad, I meant the view (From your article). You associate the viewModels with views using a DataTemplate. But it only works if the view has a parameterless constructor. How can I fix it?

Comment: @EmpereurAiman The `DataTemplate` tells WPF how to draw the ViewModel. It does not actually create it. That's the responsibility of something else... typically for me if it's the highest level in my application it will be the code behind, otherwise it will be another ViewModel. There's a more complete code sample [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9331487/302677) if you want.

Comment: Thanks Rachel. I checked your blogs and the view-model first approach you use solved a lot of problems for me. :)