# How best to apply WPF MVVM?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

I'm trying to setup an MVVM style application, and I think I'm getting myself into a few knots with the interactions of these items and hoping someone can help. Am I doing something really wrong here?

I suppose my main 2 questions are

1. How should I be going from my model to my view. Currently I'm trying to do this via a converter.
2. If using a converter is correct, how do I get this working correctly? I believe the datacontext set on the Node constructor is replaced by the XAML that includes the converter.

My classes (simplified a bit):

**IFieldDescription**

```
 // Interface that is supposed to be the Model
 public interface IFieldDescription
 {
    String Name { get; }
    bool Disabled { get; }
 }
```

**NodeModel**

```
// Class that is supposed to be the ViewModel
public class NodeModel : NotifyPropertyChanged
{   
    internal NodeModel() { }

    public NodeModel(IFieldDescription fieldDescription)
    {               
       this.FieldDescription = fieldDescription;
    }

    protected IFieldDescription FieldDescription
    {
       get { return this.fieldDescription; }
       set {
        this.fieldDescription = value;
        this.OnPropertyChanged("Name");
        this.OnPropertyChanged("Disabled");
        this.OnPropertyChanged("PrimaryKey");       }
    }
    private IFieldDescription fieldDescription;

    public String Name { get { return this.FieldDescription.Name; } }
    public Boolean Disabled { get { return this.FieldDescription.Disabled; } }
}
```

**Node**
Code behind

```
public Node(NodeModel model)
{
   this.DataContext = model;
   this.InitializeComponent();
}
```

XAML

```
<UserControl xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:GO" x:Class="GO.Node" Background="White"
    >

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>    <!-- Primary Key Icon -->
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>    <!-- Type Icon -->
            <ColumnDefinition/>                 <!-- Node Text -->
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>    <!-- Option Cog -->
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>    <!-- Match Icon -->
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>    
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <local:AttributeDataTypeConverter x:Key="DateTypeConverter"/>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <Image Grid.Column="0" Source="C:\Users\ian.wright\Documents\Expression\Blend 4\Projects\GO\GO\Resources\Images\PrimaryKey.png" Stretch="None" Visibility="{Binding Path=IsPrimaryKey}"/>
        <Image Grid.Column="1" Source="{Binding Path=Type, Converter={StaticResource DateTypeConverter}}" Stretch="None"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Path=Name}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,0,0,2"/>
        <Image Grid.Column="3" Source="C:\Users\ian.wright\Documents\Expression\Blend 4\Projects\GO\GO\Resources\Images\Cog.png" Stretch="None" Visibility="{Binding Path=HasOptions}"/>
        <Image Grid.Column="4" Source="{Binding Path=CastType}" Stretch="None"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**MainWindow**

```
<Window
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="d"
x:Class="GO.MainWindow"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:GO"
x:Name="Window"
Title="MainWindow"
Width="640" Height="480">

<Grid Width="200" Height="500">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <local:NodeConverter x:Key="NodeConverter"/>
        <local:ModelToViewConverter x:Key="ModelConverter"/>
    </Grid.Resources>
        <!--<ListView Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=FieldDescriptions, Converter={StaticResource ModelConverter}}">-->

    <ListView Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=FieldDescriptions}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <local:Node DataContext="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ModelConverter}}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
</Grid>
```

The data context for the mainwindow is set to a new RD() which is defined below:
**RD**

```
public class RD
    {
        private IEnumerable<IFieldDescription> GetTestData()
        {
            yield return new FieldDescription("String", true);
            yield return new FieldDescription("Integer", false);
            yield return new FieldDescription("Double", false);
            yield return new FieldDescription("Date", false);
            yield return new FieldDescription("Enum", false);
        }

        public virtual ObservableCollection<IFieldDescription> FieldDescriptions
        {
            get { return new ObservableCollection<IFieldDescription>(GetTestData()); }
        }
    }
```

Any my converter is currently defined as :

```
public class ModelToViewConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value == null)
                return null;

            if (value is IFieldDescription)
            {
                NodeModel model = new NodeModel((IFieldDescription)value);
                return new Node(model);
            }

            return null;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please, NEVER EVER set `this.DataContext` to smth in Control's constructor. You will shoot yourself in the leg with this approach. `DataContext` for control should be set only from outside, usually from its parent. Having `this.DataContext = ...` set in constructor some day you will run into a nightmare trying to understand "why my binding doesn't work on this control"

Comment: @Snowbear: Thanks for the comment, advice noted. I'm still trying to get my head around the basics of WPF so happy to admit I'm probably make a number of errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually I use `DataTemplates` for tying a `View` with a `Model` or `ViewModel`

The only place my View's code-behind ever references a Model or ViewModel is on startup when it sets the startup ViewModel as the startup View's `DataContext`. Everything else is hooked up with `DataTemplates` (or `DataTemplateSelectors` for Silverlight).

(Actually to be fair sometimes I do need to do something special and I will cast an object's `DataContext` as a ViewModel or Model in the code-behind, but those cases are rare and I view them as hacks)

For example, setting the startup View/ViewModel:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);

        var app = new ShellView();
        var context = new ShellViewModel();
        app.DataContext = context;
        app.Show();
    }
}
```

Here's an example of some DataTemplates:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:SomeViewModel}">
        <local:SomeViewForViewModel />
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:SomeModel}">
        <local:SomeViewForModel />
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

And finally, I'll use `ContentControls` in my XAML where I want to display my Views

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding SomeViewModelProperty}" />
```

or

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding SomeModelProperty}" />
```

Sometimes ContentControls are not even needed. For example, if you bound a `ListView` to an `ObservableCollection<NodeModel>`, then each item in the `ListView` would be an object of type `NodeModel` and WPF will automatically pick up the DataTemplate for that.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=CollectionOfNodeModel}">
    <ListView.Resources> <!-- Could also put this in Window.Resources -->
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:NodeModel}">
            <local:Node /> <!-- DataContext will implicitly be the NodeModel object -->
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.Resources>
</ListView>
```

The idea behind MVVM is that your entire application functions in your ViewModels, and the Views are simply a pretty UI which sits on top of the ViewModels to make them more user-friendly. In a perfect world, the View could easily be replaced by any other UI

If you're interested, I have a [simple MVVM example](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/05/08/simplemvvmexample/) on my blog which contains some examples of using the MVVM design pattern