# MVVM: Hierarchical ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, mvvm, .net-4.0

Note: The code is in vb.net, but I'm also happy with answers in C#! ;-)

I'm having one ParentView which holds a ChildView (or multiple ChildViews).

So at the moment, my ParentViewModel looks something like this:

```
Public Class ParentViewModelName
    Inherits ObservableObject

    Public Property ChildViewModelName() As ChildViewModel
       ...
    End Property
End Class
```

In the ParentView.XAML, I can easily hook my view to the viewmodel:

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <ViewModel:ParentViewModelName/>
 </UserControl.DataContext>
```

However, how should I hook my ChildViewModel to the instance defined in the ParentViewModel?

Or should I choose a different approach (e.g. Mediator Pattern / PRISM / Cinch)?

I'm looking for a good practise, which also supports larger projects.

Comment: Good design is to never hardccode `.DataContext` anywhere from within the View like this. It makes the View unusable for any other DataContext, and defeats one of the biggest benefits of MVVM - separation of UI and logic. I don't have time to write a full answer right now, but you can probably get an idea of the correct approach from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9331487/302677)

Comment: I don't think your view-model should depend on other view-models.
Why not have your view-models rely on their corresponding models instead?

Have you considered using an Event Aggregator or a simular publish/subscribe pattern?

What is your intent?

Comment: @ScottNimrod The views should be reusable. So neither the hardcoded .DataContext (as mentioned by Rachel) nor the tightly coupled ViewModel will be good.
I'm collecting some experiences with a small project. But I would like to migrate our main product from WinForms to WPF (which is a huge effort, I'm afraid).
So I guess, the "cleanest" way is to install one of the big frameworks (e.g. PRISM) and get it done with built-in functionality (such as EventAggregator and ViewModelLocator) from there.