# MVVM WPF navigating views from inside the views

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have been stuck with this problem for a few hours now. I followed this answer which seemed to be the most relevant (no frameworks) [WPF MVVM navigate views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19654295/wpf-mvvm-navigate-views), but I am missing something and it doesn't work. It only displays the .toString method on the screen instead of the actual data template.

What I have is a `MainWindow.xaml`, `View1.xaml` and `View2.xaml` and associated ViewModels. Both Views have buttons that can go to the other view. Why does ContentControl only displays .toString()?

> MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="View1Template" DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:View1Model}">
        <views:View1 />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="View2Template" DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:View2Model}">
        <views:View2 />
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentView}" />
</Grid>
```

> MainWindowViewModel.cs

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
{

    private ViewModelBase currentView;

    public ViewModelBase CurrentView
    {
        get
        {
            return currentView;
        }
        set
        {
            if (currentView != value)
            {
                currentView = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("CurrentView");
            }
        }
    }

    public MainWindowViewModel ()
    {
        CurrentView = new View1Model();
    }

}
```

How should I make this work? Moreover, where should the commands for swapping the views be? In this `MainWindowViewModel.cs`?

DataContext is set in the code-behind.

Comment: remove `x:Key="..."` from DataTemplates. if they are not named, they are picked up based on DataType. Linked example doesn't have `x:Key`. also linked example says about ICommand in a *view model*

Comment: This may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6114865/885920

Comment: Can you please write this part of x:key as an answer? It solved the main problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to make example work remove `x:Key="..."` from DataTemplates.

---

ContentControl binds to CurrentView. CurrentView is a view model instance and doesn't have visual representation (doesn't derive from framework `Visual` class).

There is no `ContentTemplate`, so ContentControl tries to find a default DataTemplate for `View1Model` (or `View2Model`) type. but both DataTemplates which are declared in Resources, are not default, they are named with `x:Key`. So ContentControl finds nothing and falls back to guaranted method: display string representation of Content, because every .NET object has `ToString()` method.